# Storing the values of two dropdown values in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, selectize.js

I have two dropdown menus and I would like to store the values of the user selected value. I am making use of selectize library for the dropdowns. Html:

```
 <div style="max-width: 200px">
        <select
          id="dropdown-1"
          multiple="multiple"> 
          <option value="bob">bob</option>
          <option value="mary">mary</option>
        </select>
      </div>

   <div style="max-width: 200px">
        <select
          id="dropdown-2"
          multiple="multiple"> 
          <option value="bread">bread</option>
          <option value="bread">bread</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

Javascript:

```
//variables to store the values
let nameValues = "";
let foodValues = "";

//The selectize library
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  let $market = $("#dropdown-1").selectize({
    sortField: "text",
    placeholder: "Choose a name...",
    onChange: (value) => {
      nameValues += value.join("&");
    },
  });
  let $msm = $("#dropdown-2").selectize({
    sortField: "text",
    placeholder: "Choose a food value...",
    onChange: (value) => {
      foodValues += value.join("&");
    },
  });
console.log(nameValues)
console.log(foodValues)
```

Putting the console.log(nameValues) and  console.log(foodValues) works inside of the onchange function of each. But I want to be able to get the values and use it in another function like this:

```
const getDropDownValues = (dropval_1, dropval_2)=>{
  console.log(dropval_1 + dropval_2)
}

getDropDownValues(nameValues, foodValues).....
```

when I console.log each variable it shows empty no value is displayed. what am I doing wrong is there a way to better achieve this?

Comment: Put the `console.log(nameValues)` inside the `onChange` method

Comment: yes it does work, but can it be stored outside that function, I would like to use those two values in another function

Comment: You have to call `getDropDownValues(nameValues, foodValues)` after the `onChange` event of the dropdowns have been triggered. Eg. inside an event listener or something similar otherwise you will get invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$market.getValue()` and `$msm.getValue()` outside selectize callbacks at any time. The API documentation for the same can be found [here](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md).

Another option you have, is to have two global variables (like you have currently), and inside the change listener, just update global variable values using the latest values. (Although, i don't prefer this, since it means keeping the same values at two places and may cause conflicts/bugs if update is done incorrectly).